# Why does my asynchronous function freeze the UI?

Tags: macos, flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm building a Flutter app to send MIDI SysEx messages using a plugin called `flutter_midi_command`. It uses a binding to a Swift class to send MIDI messages via CoreMIDI on MacOS and iOS. The overall process in the app is the following:

User selects MIDI device -> User selects file -> File is sent via MIDI.

These steps are implemented in separate screens. The file is read in the `update_select` widget and passed into the `updater` widget. There's a `LinearProgressIndicator` to display feedback to the user.

My problem is, that the progress indicator of the `updater` screen is not shown while the data is sent. In my understanding, I have to start sending the data after the widget is built because the progress needs to be updated. I think the sending function must be asynchronous because the UI would freeze otherwise. But for some reason the UI still freezes. What am I missing here?

updater.dart (there's the problem)

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer' as dev;
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_midi_command/flutter_midi_command.dart';

import 'oxi_one.dart' as oxiOne;
import 'package:oxi_companion_flttr/common/oxi_theme.dart';

class Updater extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UpdaterState createState() => _UpdaterState();
}

class _UpdaterState extends State<Updater> {

  MidiCommand _midiCommand = MidiCommand();
  double _progress = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
       final Uint8List _syxData = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Uint8List;
       send(_syxData).then((value) => null).whenComplete(() => Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/update_succeeded', (_)=>(false)));
     });

  void dispose() {
    _midiCommand.disconnectDevice(oxiOne.OxiOne().device);
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> send(Uint8List _syxData) async {
    _midiCommand.connectToDevice(oxiOne.OxiOne().device);

    int chunkSize = _syxData.indexWhere((element) => element == 0xf7) + 1;
    int chunks = (_syxData.lengthInBytes % chunkSize == 0) ?
    _syxData.lengthInBytes ~/ chunkSize :
    _syxData.lengthInBytes ~/ chunkSize + 1;

    for (int chunkCount = 1, start = 0, end = chunkSize; chunkCount <= chunks; chunkCount++ ){
      if (chunkCount == chunks){
        dev.log("sending last chunk: ");
        _midiCommand.sendData(_syxData.sublist(start));
      } else {
        _midiCommand.sendData(_syxData.sublist(start, end));
        dev.log("last byte of this chunk $chunkCount is ${_syxData[end-1]}");
      }
      start = chunkCount*chunkSize;
      end = start+chunkSize;
      sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 190));
      if (chunkCount == chunks) {
        return;
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _progress = 100/chunks*chunkCount;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: OxiAppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Installing update",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
              fontSize: 24
          ),
        ),
        disableNav: true
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 80.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
              child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                value: _progress,
                minHeight: 8,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "Update in progress, hold your breath!",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

update_select.dart (passes the data as `Uint8List` to the updater)

```dart
import 'dart:developer' as dev;
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart' as mobilePicker;
import 'package:file_picker_desktop/file_picker_desktop.dart' as desktopPicker;

import 'oxi_one.dart' as oxiOne;

import 'package:oxi_companion_flttr/common/oxi_theme.dart';


class UpdateSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UpdateSelectState createState() => _UpdateSelectState();
}

class _UpdateSelectState extends State<UpdateSelect> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: OxiAppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Install Update",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
              fontSize: 24
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 80.0,
                  child: Text("Your Oxi One firmware is up2date!"),
                )
              ],
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: _selectUpdate,
                    child: Text(
                        "I feel adventurous!",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0
                        ),
                    )
                )
              ],
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  void _selectUpdate() async {
    Uint8List? syxData;
    if (Platform.isLinux || Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isWindows) {
      desktopPicker.FilePickerResult? result = await desktopPicker.pickFiles(
        dialogTitle: "Select update file",
        allowedExtensions: ["syx"],
        type: desktopPicker.FileType.custom,
        withData: true
      );
      if (result != null) {
        syxData = result.files.first.bytes as Uint8List;
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/update_file_fail', (_)=>(false));
      }
    } else {
      mobilePicker.FilePickerResult? result = await mobilePicker.FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: mobilePicker.FileType.any,
        withData: true
      );
      if (result != null) {
        syxData = result.files.single.bytes as Uint8List;
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/update_file_fail', (_)=>(false));
      }
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/updater', (_)=>(false), arguments: syxData);

  }
}
```